# Get a list from a data frame in R

Tags: r

I have the data in the following format

```
col1 <- c('a','a','b','b')
col2 <- c(0.5,0.3,1,1)
df <- data.frame(col1,col2)
```

I want the output to be in the following format:

```
$a
[1] 0.5 3.0

$b
[1] 1.0 1.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
split(df$col2, df$col1)

$a
[1] 0.5 0.3

$b
[1] 1 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Besides the `split` approach by [@sindri_baldur](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72287732/12158757), we can use `aggregate` as well

```
> aggregate(.~col1,df,list)$col2
[[1]]
[1] 0.5 0.3

[[2]]
[1] 1 1
```